# Castle Windsor registering types

Tags: c#, interface, castle-windsor

Im looking for an answer to what I suspect is a fairly basic question.

I am starting out using Windsor now and am struggling to figure out how to register an interface...

In my app I have an IRepository interface which is passed into my controllers in their constructors. I want Windsor to resolve these dependencies for me but am struggling to figure out how to do this.

So my IRepository looks a little like this:

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    List<string> GetList();
}
```

This is implemented in two classes:

```
public class Repository1 : IRepository
{
    public List<string> GetList(){...}
}

public class Repository2 : IRepository
{
    public List<string> GetList(){...}
}
```

My Controller looks a little like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository _repo;

    public HomeController(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
...
```

Now I would like to register IRepository to resolve to either of the implementations Repository1 or Repository2 (Eventually I want to be able to figure out which Repository is availabe in other assemblies and load whichever is available)

Now, I have register the classes and change the constructor to take an instance of one of the classes and that works, but I want to do it against the interface... and thats where Im struggling.

I would also like this to be generic enough that if I have an IWhatever and a class that implements it that windsor would be able to resolve that too without having to register each and every one...

I have this (Which works)

```
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<Repository1>()
    .BasedOn(typeof(IRepository))
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .LifestyleTransient());
```

But its only registering Repository1... Any help appreciated, in the mean time Ill be back reading the documentation again and seeing if it sinks in this time!

Thanks

Comment: Are Repository1 and Repository2 part of the same assembly?

Comment: At the moment yes as this is just me messing around trying to figure stuff out, in future they will be in separate assemblies

Comment: Are there any potentionally misconfigured components after your registrations? In other words, is this array empty? `IHandler[] handlers = (((IDiagnosticsHost) container.Kernel.GetSubSystem(SubSystemConstants.DiagnosticsKey)).GetDiagnostic<IPotentiallyMisconfiguredComponentsDiagnostic>()).Inspect();`  (pass your `IWindsorContainer` as the `container`)

Comment: Hi,

Yes the array is empty, I have not been around to spend any more time on this, but am back at it now, hopefully will have a resolution soon!

Answer (score 0):

I think that what happens is that you are registering both your repositories, but since your controller only asks for one repository Windsor returns [the first one](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Register_more_components_for_the_same_service%3a_4) by default.

What you could do to check whether the repositories is to call container.ResolveAll() just after registration; i think that you will get two results.

To correct this, either you must tell your controller that it must resolve a list of repositories (i.e. IRepository[]) or you must narrow down the repository type that is expected. For example if your controller was `Controller<T>` and your repositories were IRepository, the selection would occur depending on the type of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-2-auto.html?m=1

this is pretty much what i was looking for, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: you should try and elaborate on what helped you, in case the link disappears. Did you check whether both repositories were registered?